# How to get the name of the td to use in the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make a table, in each row there is a button, when I click it, it show a modal-window, the idea is show the values of the row in modal-window.

At moment:

- Get a row(tr) of the table, this is ok!
- Get values of the cell(td), this is ok!
- Get attrib name of the cell(td) ;)

Please Could you help me to get the name of the cells?

Code:

```
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var $button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
          var row = $button.closest("tr"), // edit button is in the same row as data you want to change
          $tds = row.find("td"); // get all table cells in that row

          $.each($tds, function(index,value) {

            var input_name = $(this).attr("name"); // get name of cell we are evaluating (pagina, codigo, descripcion etc)
            alert(input_name);
            $([name='"' + input_name + '"']).val($(this).text()); //input name in the modal window
          });
    });


<table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod'
                                   data-toggle='table'
                                   data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                   data-show-refresh='true'
                                   data-show-toggle='true'
                                   data-sort-name='name'
                                   data-sort-order='desc'
                                   data-show-columns='true'
                                   data-pagination='true'
                                   data-search='true'>

                        <thead class='thead-inverse'>
                            <tr>  
                                <th data-field='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
                                <th data-field='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>
                                <th data-field='edicion' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>EDICIÓ</th>  
                                <th data-field='pagina' data-sortable='true'>PÀGINA</th>  
                                <th data-field='codigo' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>CODI</th>  
                                <th data-field='image' data-switchable='false'>IMATGE</th>
                                <th data-field='descripcion-cat' data-sortable='true'>DESCRIPCIÓ CAT</th> 
                                <th data-field='descripcion-esp' data-sortable='true'>DESCRIPCIÓ ESP</th> 
                                <th data-field='marca' data-sortable='true'>MARCA</th> 
                                <th data-field='gramaje' data-sortable='true'>GRAMATJE</th>
                                <th data-field='destacado' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>DESTACAT</th> 
                                <th data-field='pvp-cat' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CAT</th> 
                                <th data-field='pvp-lev' data-sortable='true'>PVP-LEV</th> 
                                <th data-field='pvp-and' data-sortable='true'>PVP-AND</th>
                                <th data-field='pvp-cen' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CEN</th>
                                <th data-field='pvp-nor' data-sortable='true'>PVP-NOR</th>
                                <th data-field='pvp-vas' data-sortable='true'>PVP-VAS</th>
                                <th data-field='pvp-spar' data-sortable='true'>PVP-SPAR</th>
                                <th data-field='user' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>USER</th>
                                <th data-field='fecha-mod' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>FECHA-MOD</th>
                                <th data-field='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                    <?php while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>  
                            <tr id='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'>
                                <td></td>
                                <?php echo $estado = EstadoIcon($row[2]); ?>
                                <td name='edicion'><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
                                <td data-pagina='pagina' name='pagina'><?php echo $row[3] ?></td> 
                                <td name='codigo'><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>  
                                <?php echo $imatge = AddImage($row[9]); ?> 
                                <td name='descripcion-cat'><?php echo $row[5] ?></td>
                                <td name='descripcion-esp'><?php echo $row[4] ?></td>
                                <td name='marca'><?php echo $row[6] ?></td> 
                                <td name='gramaje'><?php echo $row[7] ?></td>
                                <td name='destacado'><?php echo $row[8] ?></td> 
                                <td name='pvp-cat'><?php echo $row[10] ?></td>
                                <td name='pvp-lev'><?php echo $row[11] ?></td>  
                                <td name='pvp-and'><?php echo $row[12] ?></td>  
                                <td name='pvp-cen'><?php echo $row[13] ?></td> 
                                <td name='pvp-nor'><?php echo $row[14] ?></td>  
                                <td name='pvp-vas'><?php echo $row[15] ?></td> 
                                <td name='pvp-spar'><?php echo $row[16] ?></td>
                                <td name='user'><?php echo $row[17] ?></td>
                                <td name='fecha-mod'><?php echo $row[18] ?></td>
                                <td><button class='btn btn-xs edit btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">edit</i> </button></td>
                            </tr>  
                    <?php }  ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 

<div class="modal-body" id="editDetails">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" type="text"> <!-- hidden input for id -->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                CODI
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="CODI">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control" name="imagen" type="text" placeholder="IMATGE"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                EDICIÓ
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="edicion" type="text" placeholder="EDICION">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PÀGINA
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pagina" type="text" placeholder="EDICION">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                MODIF.
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="fecha-mod" type="text" placeholder="FECHA MODIFICACIÓ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                USER
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="user" type="text" placeholder="USER">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                DESC. CAT
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input class="form-control" name="descripcion-cat" type="text" placeholder="DESCRIPCIÓ CAT">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                DESC. ESP
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input class="form-control" name="descripcion-esp" type="text" placeholder="DESCRIPCIÓ ESP">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                MARCA
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input class="form-control" name="marca" type="text" placeholder="MARCA">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                GRAMATGE
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input class="form-control" name="gramaje" type="text" placeholder="GRAMATGE">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PVP-CAT
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pvp-cat" type="text" placeholder="PVP-CAT">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PVP-LEV
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pvp-lev" type="text" placeholder="PVP-LEV">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PVP-AND
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pvp-and" type="text" placeholder="PVP-AND">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PVP-NOR
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pvp-nor" type="text" placeholder="PVP-NOR">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                PVP-SPAR
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="pvp-spar" type="text" placeholder="PVP-SPAR">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2 descFields">
                                DESTACAT
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input class="form-control" name="destacat" type="text" placeholder="DESTACAT">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `alert(input_name)` is working??
are you getting the alert?

Comment: Your problem area is `$([name='"' + input_name + '"'])` seems it should be `$('[name="' + input_name +'"]')`

Comment: In my own application I used [data-* attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), these could be assigned to variables in JQuery on the event like so; `var user = $(this).data("user");` where the data attribute is; `<td data-user="foo">`

Comment: Actually with my code the alert window is working but show message 'undefined'. Now I will testing your tips.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Saxena yes it's working but show alert message 'undefined'.

Comment: @Satpal with your advice it's doesn't work too, the same result.

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst want to say that for example: <td data-page='1'> I could assign this variable: var page = $(this).data("page")??

Comment: @ruzD, yes thats how it works

Comment: can you post the table too...so that i will get a clear picture of the problem

Comment: @ruzD, [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3gb7houh/1/)

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst thanks for your example. I change <<th data-field='seleccion'....> every fields of my table to relate with the database using data-fields, this is the idea. At moment doesn't work :( I continue...

Comment: I have done two mistakes: I defined data-field in th tag and is in td tag, ok! And the second mistake I put the code over the loop, now it's working! Only I would like to assign the value of every fields at the input box of the modal-window, I updated the code with the modal-window.

Comment: Ok, it's working. Thank you very much :)